# why is it called $f^{-1}(x)$?

Tags: functions, notation, inverse-function

Why do we name the inverse function $f^{-1}(x)$? Is it nonstandard to say $f^{0}(x)=x$, $f^{1}(x)=f(x)$, $f^{2}(x)=f(f(x))$, $f^{\infty{}}(x)=f(f(f(⋯f(x)⋯)))$?

Some (all) functions can have a $f^{1/2}(x)$?

Like if $f(x)=x+1$ then $f^{1/2}(x)=x+1/2$ so $f^{1/2}(f^{1/2}(x))=(x+1/2)+1/2=x+1=f(x)$

Or if $f(x)=x^4$ then $f^{1/2}(x)=x^2$ so $f^{1/2}(f^{1/2}(x))=(x^2)^2=x^4=f(x)$

What about superscripts with complex numbers, which are supposed to be a natural phenomenon appearing anywhere that the negative reals can?

$f(f(x))$ adds the superscripts, what about multiplying them? This notation could be formalized with recursion. It could help describe the mandelbrot set more elegantly as $f^{\infty}(0)$ where $f^n(z)=f(n-1)^2+z$ . It could help people realise there exist smooth transitions between functions and themselves called on  themselves: $f^{1.5}(x)$

Most importantly, who invented this syntax? Is there an area of mathematics formally exploring this? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3396292/148510

Comment: So Newton himself may have invented it? Nice, but what about the existence of fractional function-calling? Is there an area of math studying this or am I the first(no)

Comment: A good reference (alluded to in that answer) is  Cajori, A History of Mathematical Notations

Comment: No Newton may have introduced negative exponents. Read further.  The notation $f^{-1}$ as the inverse function is attributed to Hershel (for trigonometric functions).

Comment: I guess, yeah I think you may be onto something with the fractions, about the notation, no it was not Newton, where did you get that? Ah, I see it.. but there he was not talking about functions but exponents on numbers. The genearlization to functions is your question then. I think it is also answersered there, in the answers. The only mess is with the trigonometric functions again, where $sin^2 (x)$ is NOT $sin(sin(x))$... The fractionals... mmm let us see into that more deeply, ne?

Comment: In group theory the element a^-1 is the element that satisfies the property a x a^-1 =1 where 1 is the identity. The reason for this is because one of the most natural examples of a group is the real numbers under multiplication, where the inverse of an element a is literally a^-1 so we just copy this notation. Typically when discussing functions the operation is composition so the function f^-1 satisfies the property f°f^-1=1, which is equivalent to f°f^-1(x)=x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea who invented this syntax. However, I typically use $f^{\circ n}(x)$ rather than $f^n(x)$ to denote repeated composition, since $\circ$ is the symbol used to denote function composition, and $f^n$ can be easily confused with exponentiation. (Especially when using trig functions, since $\sin^2 x$ is often used to denote $(\sin x)^2$.)

---

Regarding why $f^{-1}$ denotes the inverse function: notice that repeated function composition satisfies the following nice addition property:
$$f^{\circ m}\circ f^{\circ n}=f^{\circ (m+n)}$$
If we want to make $f^{\circ n}$ well-defined for negative $n$, but still want this nice addition property to hold true, then we need
$$f^{\circ -1}\circ f^{\circ 1}=f^{\circ 1}\circ f^{\circ -1}=f^{\circ 0}$$
and the inverse function $f^{-1}$ satisfies the desired property.

---

If you’re looking for a multiplicative analogue of the additive law
$$f^{\circ m}\circ f^{\circ n}=f^{\circ (m+n)}$$
then the following might be what you’re looking for:
$$(f^{\circ m})^{\circ n}=f^{\circ mn}$$

---

Be careful referring to $f^{\circ 1/2}$ as if it were a unique function. For example, the function $f(x)=2x+1$ has at least two half-iterates:
$$f^{\circ 1/2}(x) =^? \sqrt{2}x+\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}}$$
and
$$f^{\circ 1/2}(x) =^? -\sqrt{2}x+\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{2}}$$
So again, be careful! It’s not always uniquely defined.

Regarding which functions have half-iterates: lots of them, but if you impose the restriction that the half-iterate must be *continuous*, it turns out that continuous decreasing functions cannot have continuous half-iterates.

---

Related blog posts:

- [Fractional iterates](https://franklin.dyer.me/post/75)
- [A summary of functional iteration](https://franklin.dyer.me/post/77)
- [N-involutory rational functions](https://franklin.dyer.me/post/95)
- [Iterated polynomials](https://franklin.dyer.me/post/96)

Comment: Thank you for your response this cleared up alot about whether this has been studied in-depth. However, it bothers me that some of the "half-iterates" are not holomorphic!(infinitely differentiable, that is, the nth derivative can be constant 0 or any nonsense as long as it is continuous)

Comment: Maybe if we find some way to get the half-iterate(s) of an arbitrary complex polynomial / maclauren series, (and some functions are multi-valued and nonsense which just adds to the confusion)  maybe then we can nth-iterate anything for all n∈ℤ

Comment: @cmarangu If you’re bothered by non-holomorphic half-iterates, you may want to know that some functions have half-iterates in the form of power series, like the one here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45608/does-the-formal-power-series-solution-to-ffx-sin-x-converge?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: (+1) Clear and concise.  Nicely done!